# Subscribe MQTT broker(mosquitto) topic in Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure-functions, mqtt, mosquitto

I wanted to subscribe mqtt broker topic (mosquitto broker created in azure VM) into azure function. Unfortunately I didn't get the proper help or direction into it. Maybe I am doing something wrong with my approach.

I was following one article https://github.com/keesschollaart81/CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt/ where they are using **CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt** library but this library has a dependency of **.NETStandard 2.0** and I am using **.net 6**.
And even **.NETStandard 2.0** no longer supported in azure function.

Can't We directly subscribe mqtt broker into azure function?
Or
Do we require to integrate kafka with mqtt and then create kafka triggered azure function?

Answer (score 0):

That library should work if you don't use the azure function out-process model (binding are defined only for in-process model). The point is that the extension is based on an older MQTTnet library version which doesn't support the V5 protocol. If you don't need it should be ok.
Starting from that project, I wrote an output binding WebJobs extension available at https://github.com/mdip/azure-webjobs-mqttoutput, so in case you need to publish something perhaps this extension could help you, or if you like to extend it, you're welcome.